# Practical use of `stackalloc` keyword

Tags: c#, keyword, stackalloc

Has anyone ever actually used `stackalloc` while programming in C#? I am aware of what is does, but the only time it shows up in my code is by accident, because Intellisense suggests it when I start typing `static`, for example.

Although it is not related to the usage scenarios of `stackalloc`, I actually do a considerable amount of legacy interop in my apps, so every now and then I could resort to using `unsafe` code. But nevertheless I usually find ways to avoid `unsafe` completely.

And since stack size for a single thread in .Net is ~1Mb (correct me if I'm wrong), I am even more reserved from using `stackalloc`.

Are there some practical cases where one could say: "this is exactly the right amount of data and processing for me to go unsafe and use `stackalloc`"?

Comment: just noticed that `System.Numbers` uses it a lot https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,86404b606ba1649f

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The sole reason to use `stackalloc` is performance (either for computations or interop). By using `stackalloc` instead of a heap allocated array, you create less GC pressure (the GC needs to run less), you don't need to pin the arrays down, it's faster to allocate than a heap array, an it is automatically freed on method exit (heap allocated arrays are only deallocated when GC runs). Also by using `stackalloc` instead of a native allocator (like malloc or the .Net equivalent) you also gain speed and automatic deallocation on scope exit.

Performance wise, if you use `stackalloc` you greatly increase the chance of cache hits on the CPU due to the locality of data.

Comment: Locality of data, good point! That's what managed memory will rarely achieve when you want to allocate several structures or arrays. Thanks!

Comment: Heap allocations are usually faster for managed objects than for unmanaged because there's no free list to traverse; the CLR just increments the heap pointer.  As for locality, sequential allocations are more likely to end up colocated for long running managed processes because of heap compaction.

Comment: "it's faster to allocate than a heap array" Why's that? Just locality? Either way it's just a pointer-bump, no?

Comment: @MaxBarraclough Because you add the GC cost to heap allocations over the application lifetime. Total allocation cost = allocation + deallocation, in this case pointer bump + GC Heap, vs pointer bump + pointer decrement Stack

Answer (score 49):

I have used stackalloc to allocate buffers for [near] realtime DSP work.  It was a very specific case where performance needed to be as consistent as possible.  Note there is a difference between consistency and overall throughput - in this case I wasn't concerned with heap allocations being too slow, just with the non determinism of garbage collection at that point in the program.  I wouldn't use it in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 43):

Stackalloc initialization of spans. In previous versions of C#, the result of stackalloc could only be stored into a pointer local variable. As of C# 7.2, stackalloc can now be used as part of an expression and can target a span, and that can be done without using the unsafe keyword. Thus, instead of writing

```
Span<byte> bytes;
unsafe
{
  byte* tmp = stackalloc byte[length];
  bytes = new Span<byte>(tmp, length);
}
```

You can write simply:

```
Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[length];
```

**This is also extremely useful in situations where you need some scratch space to perform an operation, but want to avoid allo­cating heap memory for relatively small sizes**

```
Span<byte> bytes = length <= 128 ? stackalloc byte[length] : new byte[length];
... // Code that operates on the Span<byte>
```

*Source:* [C# - All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems each new version of C# gets a bit closer to C++, which is actually a good thing IMHO.

Comment: As can be seen [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/), `Span` is alas not available in .NET framework 4.7.2 and even not in 4.8... So that new language feature is still of limited use for the moment.

Comment: @Frederic: apparently, .NET framework 4.8 is the [last major version of .NET framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/). Next version of .NET Core will be called [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) (no "core" anymore, and version 4 skipped to avoid confusion with the framework), so the future of .NET is .NET Core, and it's now evident that .NET Framework apps won't get this update. I also believe the idea is to remove .NET Standard in the future (since there will be just ".NET" from this point on).

Answer (score 26):

`stackalloc` is only relevant for unsafe code. For managed code you can't decide where to allocate data. Value types are allocated on the stack per default (unless they are part of a reference type, in which case they are allocated on the heap). Reference types are allocated on the heap.

The default stack size for a plain vanilla .NET application is 1 MB, but you can change this in the PE header. If you're starting threads explicitly, you may also set a different size via the constructor overload. For ASP.NET applications the default stack size is only 256K, which is something to keep in mind if you're switching between the two environments.

Comment: Is it possible to change the default stack size from Visual Studio?

Comment: @configurator: Not as far as I am aware.

Comment: This is no longer the case with C# 7.2's `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. @Anth pointed this out in an answer below.

Answer (score 11):

Late answer but I believe still helpful.

I came to this question and I was still curios to see the performance difference so I created the following benchmark (used BenchmarkDotNet NuGet Package):

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
[RankColumn]
public class Benchmark1
{
    //private MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    static void FakeRead(byte[] buffer, int start, int length)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte) (i % 250);
    }

    static void FakeRead(Span<byte> buffer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte) (i % 250);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void AllocatingOnHeap()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        FakeRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ConvertingToSpan()
    {
        var buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        FakeRead(buffer);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void UsingStackAlloc()
    {
        Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[1024];
        FakeRead(buffer);
    }
}
```

And this where the results

```
|           Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Rank |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|-----:|-------:|----------:|
|  UsingStackAlloc | 704.9 ns | 13.81 ns | 12.91 ns |    1 |      - |         - |
| ConvertingToSpan | 755.8 ns |  5.77 ns |  5.40 ns |    2 | 0.0124 |   1,048 B |
| AllocatingOnHeap | 839.3 ns |  4.52 ns |  4.23 ns |    3 | 0.0124 |   1,048 B |
```

**This benchmark shows that using `stackalloc` is the fastest solution and also it uses no allocations!** If you are curios how to use the NuGet Package BenchmarkDotNet then watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWmufbVF2A4&t=353s).

Comment: Probably it indicates that BenchmarkDotNet does not measure stackalloc alloctions.

Comment: Stack allocations are impactless, inconsequential, and irrelevant. You ***would not want*** any tool to measure them even if it could.

Comment: FYI, the runtime zeros the memory allocation. Add `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SkipLocalsInit]` to make it simply incrementy the stack pointer.   For the other methods, doing so will just mean the variable pointing to the arrays won't be zero initialized upon entry.

Answer (score 8):

There are some great answers in this question but I just want to point out that

**Stackalloc can also be used to call native APIs**

Many native functions requires the caller to allocate a buffer to get the return result. For example, the [CfGetPlaceholderInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfgetplaceholderinfo) function in `cfapi.h` has the following signature.

```
HRESULT CfGetPlaceholderInfo(
HANDLE                    FileHandle,
CF_PLACEHOLDER_INFO_CLASS InfoClass,
PVOID                     InfoBuffer,
DWORD                     InfoBufferLength,
PDWORD                    ReturnedLength);
```

In order to call it in C# through interop,

```
[DllImport("Cfapi.dll")]
public static unsafe extern HResult CfGetPlaceholderInfo(IntPtr fileHandle, uint infoClass, void* infoBuffer, uint infoBufferLength, out uint returnedLength);
```

You can make use of stackalloc.

```
byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[1024];
CfGetPlaceholderInfo(fileHandle, 0, buffer, 1024, out var returnedLength);
```