# Is int[] a reference type or a value type?

Tags: c#, .net

I know an int is a value type, but what are arrays of value types? Reference types? Value types? I want to pass an array to a function to check something. Should I just pass the array, as it will just pass the reference of it, or should I pass it as ref?

Comment: In the future, you can check if something is passed by reference or by value by creating a variable, passing that variable into a method that changes that variable, and the checking what the value of that variable is after it's run through the method. If it's the same, its passed by value, different, passed by reference.

Comment: @darkassassin93: Passing by reference or by value is unrelated to whether something is a reference type or a value type. (Value types can be passed by reference and reference types can be passed by value.)

Comment: In most cases if you can store [null] inside a field or variable you can assume that it is a ref type. The exceptions certainly are nullable types (Nullable<int> or int?) as well as strings.

Comment: @NoëlWidmer Strings are not an exception: they're ref types.

Comment: @ArthurCastro Argree to 50%: strings inherit from class that means they are reference types. However their equality is based on identity (value comparism) rather than reference and their pass behaviour is overriden to match the behaviour of value types. Basically they are reference types by definition but behave more like value types by implementation.

Comment: @NoëlWidmer I understand your point but, even that they seem to behave like value types, they aren't. Strings are immutable ref types which overrides the == operator and, different than value types, they are allocated in the heap instead of stack.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

> Arrays are mechanisms that allow you
>   to treat several items as a single
>   collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common
>   Language Runtime (CLR) supports
>   single-dimensional arrays,
>   multidimensional arrays, and jagged
>   arrays (arrays of arrays). All array
>   types are implicitly derived from
>   System.Array, which itself is derived
>   from System.Object. This means that
>   **all arrays are always reference types**
>   which are allocated on the managed
>   heap, and your app's variable contains
>   a reference to the array and not the
>   array itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985948.aspx

Comment: Value types inherit from System.ValueType which itself inherits from System.Object. So just because Array derives from System.Object does not mean it's a reference type. What makes System.Array a reference type is that it's instances are copied by reference. IOW, concentrate on the fact that System.Array is a class.  That is what makes it a reference type.

Comment: <nitpick>I know it may look like the documentation is implying that System.Array deriving from System.Object makes it a reference type. Although it may not be true that any type that derives from System.Object is a reference type, the only exception to this rule is System.ValueType, which is treated differently by the compiler.</nitpick>

Comment: The link above is broken. Here is another msdn link which shows the inheritance hierarchy of System.Array: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anything that derives from System.Object is a reference type, UNLESS it also derives from System.ValueType.
@P.Brian.Mackey just because a type is a class doesn't mean it's a reference type, because behind the scenes, structs are just classes which derive from System.ValueType.

Answer (score 40):

The simplest test for reference type vs. value type is that reference types can be `null`, but value types can not.

Comment: ... except for nullable value types, which are nullable (you can set the value to null, which means the null value for the type rather than a null *reference*) and are still value types.

Comment: Never thought of doing that when trying to understand if they're value types or not! Great idea.

Answer (score 22):

Arrays (even of value types like int) are reference types in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx:

> In C#, arrays are actually objects. System.Array is the abstract base type of all array types.

Answer (score 8):

Test to verify if it's a reference or value type:

```
// we create a simple array of int
var a1 = new int[]{1,2,3};
// copy the array a1 to a2
var a2 = a1;
// modify the first element of a1
a1[0]=2;
// output the first element of a1 and a2
Console.WriteLine("a1:"+a1[0]); // 2
Console.WriteLine("a2:"+a2[0]); // 2
//**************************
// all the two variable point to the same array
// it's reference type!
//**************************
```

You can test it online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UWFP45

Comment: It would just have been easier to create an array and attempt to assign it to null. Compilation would fail if it was a value type..

Comment: Be forewarned.  Once C#8 is released, it will also fail if you are using the nullable reference types feature as non-nullable reference types can't accept null either.

Answer (score 7):

First I want to tell you that Array is a reference type. Why? I explain throw one example over here.

**Example:**

```
int val = 0; // this is a value type ok
int[] val1 = new int[20] // this is a reference type because space required to store 20 integer value that make array allocated on the heap.
```

Also reference types can be null whereas value types can't.

[value type stored in Stack and reference type stored in Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXic.png)

You can pass array to function using out or ref. Only initialize methods are different.

[more..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to the other answers that though int[] is a reference type, with the introduction of `stackalloc` in C# you can allocate an array in stack as a value type. This may give you performance gain since placing array to stack reduces GC pressure (by the way, talking about value types in general you may often hear that value type is allocated in stack; it is not always true:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc

> A stackalloc expression allocates a block of memory on the stack. A
> stack allocated memory block created during the method execution is
> automatically discarded when that method returns. You cannot
> explicitly free the memory allocated with stackalloc. A stack
> allocated memory block is not subject to garbage collection and
> doesn't have to be pinned with a fixed statement.

An example of `stackalloc` usage:

```
    Span<int> numbers = stackalloc int[10];
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < numbers.Length; ctr++)
        numbers[ctr] = ctr + 1;
    foreach (int i in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Using this technique don't forget about the limited stack memory. The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc provides the necessary information on how to use `stackalloc` safely considering this limitation.

Additionally, here is an answer that discusses the practical usage of `stackalloc`: [Practical use of `stackalloc` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785226/practical-use-of-stackalloc-keyword)

Answer (score 3):

The array itself is a reference type. The values of that array are value or reference types as determined by the array data type. In your example, the array is a reference type and the values are value types.

All single-dimension arrays implicitly implement `IList<T>`, where `<T>` is the data type of the array. You can use that interface as the data type of your method parameter instead. You could also use `IEnumerable<T>` for the data type. In either case (or even if you just use `int[]`) you shouldn't need to explicitly pass it as a `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

//The reference to the array is passed by value. This is the source of the confusion :-)
...

```
        int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        modifContenuSansRef(test);
        Console.WriteLine(test[0]); // OK --> 99 le contenu du tableau est modifié

        modifTailleSansRef(test);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Length); // KO --> 4 La taille n'est pas modifiée

    }

    static void modifContenuSansRef(int[] t)
    {
        t[0] = 99;
    }

    static void modifTailleSansRef(int[] t)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref t, 8);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays  always are reference types.it does not matter array would contain  value type like int or reference type like string.When you declare array for example

`int[] integers=new int[10]`;

integers variable  itself contains only  reference to the array which will reside in heap.

Also there is many people  mention  that you could  differ value type from reference type  just depend on the fact thhat variable could be null or not.
I would like to mention that in the c# currently value types also can be null

for instance

```
int? integer=null
```

and it is not  good way to identify the type is reference or value only depends on the fact  variable could be null or not.

Comment: There is a clear indication when are making a value type as null there we need special syntactical help which points us to still and ever valid point that the value types cannot be ever plainly assigned a null value.

Answer (score -3):

Just a bit of an insight:

For example, `int` represents a single integer, `int[]` represents an array of integers.

To initialize the array with specific dimensions, you can use the `new` keyword, giving the size in the square brackets after the type name:

```
//create a new array of 32 ints.
int[] integers = new int[32];
```

All arrays are reference types and follow reference semantics. Hence, in this code, even though the individual elements are primitive value types, the `integers` array is a reference type. So if you later write:

```
int[] copy = integers;
```

this will simply assign the whole variable copy to refer to the same array, it won't create a new array.

C#'s array syntax is flexible, it allows you to declare arrays without initializing them so that the array can be dynamically sized later in the program. With this technique, you are basically creating a null reference and later pointing that reference at a dynamically allocated stretch of memory locations requested with a `new` keyword:

```
int[] integers;
integers = new int[32];
```

Thank You.