# Array value seems to be different while in for loop compared to when it isn't

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with values. I use two for loops to loop through each item and add a value to them. While in the array they return the correct value, but when it exits and I get the value it is completely different. For example:

- Before loop: `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`
- During loop: `[[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]`
- After loop `[[50,50][65,65][90,90]]`

It just seems to randomly change.

```
int[,] squareB = baseSquare;
int[,] squareC = baseSquare;
int[,] squareD = baseSquare;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", squareB[0, 1]);
for (int x = 0; x < sub; ++x)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < sub; ++y)
     {
          squareB[x, y] += 9;
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", squareB[x, y]);
          squareC[x, y] += 18;
          squareD[x, y] += 27;
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}", squareB[0, 1]);
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: Magic!!! mind posting your code. so that, we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Obviously you are doing it wrong, we need the code.

Comment: Code added, though I dunno how much use it is as you can't know what baseSquare is. It is programmatically filled.

Comment: Just to be sure; those are the outputs *every* time; correct? Its not actually *randomly* changing?

Comment: Yes they are always the same output, but they seem to just change from when it is in the loop and when it is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying the exact same array tree times at every single loop iteration:

```
      squareB[x, y] += 9;
      squareC[x, y] += 18;
      squareD[x, y] += 27;
```

These all change the exact same value.

Comment: There are three separate arrays. They are simply based of the same original array.

Comment: @auragar no, [arrays are reference types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type). All three variables point to the same array.

Comment: Looking at your code - they are not. You're assigning `baseSquare` to all of them, which just assigns the reference - it doesn't copy the array.

Comment: Then therein lies the problem. How would one create copies and not references with arrays.

Comment: `Array.Clone(baseSquare)`