# VB.net Keyed Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, key

I would like to build an array whose rows are keyed with a string.  The rows need not have the same number of columns (jagged array) or have values in each column.  I want to be able to update columns in an existing row of the array.

I tried using a Dictionary.

```
Dim ToolUsers as New Dictionary(Of String, Array)
Dim UserData() As String = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
```

The `Of String` lets me access any particular row based on the `String` value but `Array` is a reference type and always points to the current values stored in the `UserData` array instead of being a value type and storing the array values in the `Dictionary`.

I looked at an `Array` of `Array`s but it does not appear to allow access to existing rows via a key or allow updating the existing values.

Does such a construct exist in VB.net?

Comment: The Dictionary should work. You need to create a new array for each new Dictionary item, you can't just modify the values of an existing array and expect to create a new Dictionary item with different data.

Comment: Hard to see why value type behavior is important to you.  Maybe you are overlooking Array.Copy().

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using a `Dictionary`, but arrays in .NET [are reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1533757/2278086), so you need to be careful how you populate your dictionary, and not reuse the same array if you really want different data in each item.  e.g.

```vb
' Create a dictionary from string to array of string
Dim x = New Dictionary(Of String, String())()
x("A") = New String() { "A1", "A2", "A3" }
' A : A1, A2, A3
x("A")(1) = "A2x"
' A : A1, A2x, A3
Dim y = New String() { "Y1", "Y2" }
x("Y1") = y ' points to same array as y
x("Y2") = DirectCast(y.Clone(), String()) ' shallow copy of y, which is OK since String is immutable
' A : A1, A2x, A3
' Y1 : Y1, Y2
' Y2 : Y1, Y2
y(0) = "Y1x"
' A : A1, A2x, A3
' Y1 : Y1x, Y2
' Y2 : Y1, Y2
```