# Does C# have POD types?

Tags: c#

Is `int` in C# considered to be a POD type? Isn't an `int` a class in C# (or a struct with methods at least)?

---

*Edit: POD types (Plain Old Data Types)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# has so-called [value-types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s1ax56ch(v=vs.120).aspx). Technically, all structs and primitives are value types. So if you build your hierarchies from structs only, you have what in C++ would probably be called POD.

Comment: Just one more thing: strings are not primitives in C# (they're reference types with value type comparison semantics). So you cannot use them in this context.

Comment: Correct, `System.String` and it's alias `string` are classes. That means it's reference types. You would need to actually use a char array. But I'd strongly advise against it. There are better ways.

Comment: My understanding of POD types is that you can copy the raw memory of an `int` for example to another `int` (because they don't allocate memory on the heap, so there is no harm). So can I do that in C# (not sure however how to copy raw memory in C#, if possible at all)?

Comment: @johnny92 you probably could just copy all bytes on value-types. But nobody would do so in C#. There is just no need to do so.

Comment: @nvoigt (char) arrays are reference types in .NET. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533770/95976

Comment: C# 'struct' and C++ 'struct' have very little to do with each other.  POD types are usually implemented as structs in C++ just as a convention.  C# has no natural POD type - POD usually means "just data", so there is no type or convention in C# which implies this.  At least in C++, there is a convention that PODs are implemented via structs (but again, C++ structs and C# structs are orthogonal).