# C# assigning variables

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I found something that bothers me, it would be great if one of you could explain it to me. Maybe this question was asked before, but I'm really out of ideas how to name it. Here's the problem:

```
array1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
array2 = array1;
array1[0] = 10
Console.WriteLine(array2[0]); // - it will say "10" besides of "1"
```

and when I use normal variables instead of arrys, like, ie:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
a = 10;
Console.WriteLine(b); // - this one will have value "5" instead of 10.
```

I know how to copy arrys with values, I'm just curious why it works like that.

Comment: `int` is value type, but arrays are reference types. Read about **Value types vs Reference types**

Comment: Because `array1` and `array2` are pointing to the same array. Arrays are reference types, while `int` is not.

Comment: What about this as a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type

Comment: C# does shallow copies.  Takes a while to get used to it if you come from a C++ background.

Comment: It's a matter of the difference between valuetypes and reference types. an array is a reference type means the reference points to an address in the heap memory. if you say array2 = array1 you tell the reference of array2 to point to the reference of array1 ... to the same location in memory

Comment: The question is a little basic, but I wouldn't say there is anything inherently wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable array1 does not have a value like 1 or 'c', instead it holds an address that points to the place in memory where the data is stored.

So array2 = array1 was just giving array2 the same address as array1... they both point to the same place.

If you want to allocate a new chunk of memory, you'd have to declare a **new** array: int[] array2 = new int[5]; This reserves 5*32 bits in memory for your new array and gives array2 the address of the first bit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you say `array2 = array1;` then it means that you have two variables that refer to the same array.

If you want to copy then you can try this:

```
Array.Copy(array1, array2, array2.Length);
```

To explain it more actually you are not copying the array since array is a reference type when you say `array2 = array1;` then what it actually does is that it assigns another variable to point to the same array.And you only have one instance of it. So even if you change the data using one of the variable then the changes will not be reflected in your result and hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is difference between value and references type. Please read this article: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html
It should explain you how it works :)