# How does Array.Reverse work?

Tags: c#, arrays, char, reverse

I have this simple piece of code..

```
bool isTrue(char[] number)
{
    char[] reverse = number;
    Array.Reverse(reverse);
}
```

When debugging the application I saw that number is reversed too. Can someone explain to me why? Is it related to how char arrays work, or am I missing something?

Comment: @SonerGönül - `number` is a reference to the array in the code.

Comment: You can read about parameter passing here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: and about arrays in C# here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533757/238902

Comment: Thank you for the useful tips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
char[] reverse = number;
```

you are not creating a copy of the array, but just another reference to it.

If you want to copy the array, you can use [`.Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
char[] reverse = number.Clone();
```

Comment: Thank you. Does that only happens with char arrays? or is it the same with int arrays and other type of arrays?

Comment: This is true for all arrays, regardless of type.

Comment: Thank you for the inofrmation

Answer (score 2):

Try using [number.CopyTo(reverse, 0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `char[] reverse = number;`