# why delegate work as ref?

Tags: c#, delegates, ref

I have program

```
    public delegate T Transformer<T>(T arg);
    public class Util
    {
        public static void Transform<T>(T[] values, Transformer<T> t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                values[i] = t(values[i]);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };
            Util.Transform(values, Square); // Hook in Square
            foreach (int i in values)
            Console.Write(i + " "); // 1 4 9
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static int Square(int x) => x * x;
    }
```

Why Util.Transform(values, Square) changes values[] array?  It is already works like reference variable. I just wanna yo see output result not changing the source array named "values[]".

Comment: Because you are assigning new values to it?

Comment: What "delegate" works as "ref" according to you?

Comment: "Why [...] changes values[] array?" I guess because you implemented it that way? "Can I add some ref?" What do you mean? Do want to change the method so that it returns a new array instead?

Comment: I do not wanna to change values of "values " array . I wanna result of function applying to it but I wanna source unchanged

Comment: Then either change that method so that it creates a new array or copy the array before you call it.

Comment: If you don't want to change the values, why are you changing them? Do you want a read-only array instead?

Comment: I just wanna result.

Comment: You will need better English than that I'm afraid

Comment: That's not the delegate's fault, the fact is that in the .Net framework, [all arrays are reference types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type)

Comment: Yes. But I learn and would know that function accessing them directly not copying them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the method like that:

```
public class Util
{
    public static T[] Transform<T>(T[] values, Transformer<T> t)
    {
        return values.Select(x => t(x)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
var result = Utils.Transform(values, Square);
```

---

If you can't change that method, then you need to copy the array before calling:

```
var result = values.ToArray();
Utils.Transform(result, Square);
```

Comment: Just wanted to type something like that. Bottom line, your Transformer method should not update your input, instead, it should create a new array or (List<T>), populate it with transformed values and return. This way you're avoiding side effect you now have. Side effects are not a good practice. Why those values get changed? Well, because you have provided an array of values. You're accessing value directly in memory via its address in an array, not on stack as you might think. This solution is better approach then to create a copy of the original array an pass in.

Comment: I would try but I do not need copying or creating new array

Comment: Yes, I know that array is reference type.

Comment: return values.Select(x => t(x)).ToArray(); Why do I need that? This is already outputs array.

Comment: public static T[] Transform<T>(T[] values, Transformer<T> t)
        {
            return values.Select(x => t(x)).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
               values[i] = t(values[i]);        
        } How can I simplify that?

Comment: @ifooi I did not mention any `for` loop in my code. Why did you mix them together? You should use the method I showed, without the `for` loop.

Comment: @RenéVogt, cause I need to apply square method.

Comment: @ifooi yes, that is done by the `Select`.

Comment: @RenéVogt, Yes, thanks! It is applied square functtion. I appreciate your solution. Best!