# Why the parameter send to function get changed

Tags: c#

I remember when talking function pass parameters, it is said the parameter will NOT get its value changed during function execution. but in my example, I observed my initial parameter value changed:

```
public static void main()
{
    int[] a = new int[]{some int array};
    int[] b = SortArray(a);
    Output(a);
}

internal static int[] SortArray(int[] a)
{
    int[] c = new int[a.length];
    //Sort process, during which, both c[] and a[] are changing
    return c;
}
```

when executing `Output(a);` I found my `a` is not the original one anymore. what's the trick here?

Comment: You'll need to share the code of `SortArray` in order to get a sensible answer

Comment: parameters are not immutable in c#. depends on what you're doing with the a array, it could change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is int\[\] a reference type or a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type)

Comment: Because all array in c# are referance type, so if you pass an array to a method and do something like update or delete value, the values of array will completely change .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it is said the parameter will NOT get its value changed

That is right*. The confusion you have here might be because you misunderstood what "change" here means.

Arrays in C# are reference types. This means that variables of array types do not store the arrays themselves, but rather a reference to the actual array, which is somewhere else in memory.

`a`'s *value* is not the array, it is the reference. As long as `a` is referring to the same array, I can say that `a`'s value is not changed.

In your method, you probably did something like:

```
a[0] = <something else>;
```

This is not modifying the value of `a`. You are modifying the actual array object. Modifying the value of `a` would be something like:

```
a = new int[10]; // a now references a new array
```

So that's why the changes reflect - there is only one array to start with, both the parameter `a` and the local variable `a` refer to that.

---

*Actually, if you use the `ref` modifier, the parameter's value can be changed because it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in .NET are an object on the heap, so you have a reference.

That reference is passed by value, ergo changes to the contents of the array will be seen by the caller, yet reassignment of the array wont

> //Sort process, during which, both c[] and a[] are changing

Don't change `a[x]`, problem sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this. You should avoid returning array, just pass it as reference / pointer. Also forget all about java array declaration (order of brackets)

```
public static void main()
{
    int a[] = {3,1,2};
    int* sorted = SortArray(a, a.length);
    Output(sorted);
    delete[] sorted;
}

internal static int* SortArray(int* a, int length)
{
    int* c = new int[length];
    //Sort process, during which, both c[] and a[] are changing
    return c;
}
```