# Array.reverse reverses both current array and initial array but why?

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I dont understand why reversing the second array, also reverses the first array...Thanks to whoever can explain why.

```
char[] input = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char[] inputnew = input;     
Array.Reverse(inputnew);
Console.WriteLine(new string(input));
Console.WriteLine(new string(inputnew));
```

Output: 
olleh
olleh

Comment: Because it has a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533770/2630817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `=` doesn't create a **copy** of the array but rather you have two references pointing to the **very same array**.

In other words, there is a single array with two references pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

The first array **(input)** memory address is point to the second array  **(inputnew)**, so, any one place is changes is made effect the two variables.

because, two variables are pointing to the same memory address.

Reference types are always pointing to the memory address. the value types are always pointing to the value

more details http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
char[] inputnew = input;
```

you copy the *reference* of array `input` to the *reference* of inputnew. This is how object oriented programing work. You always have reference of objects. That's why the types are also called *Reference Type*. On the other side you have *Value types* which actually copy the *value*, like `int` and `boolean`.

If you want to copy the actual values of your Array, you have to use the function `Array.Copy(sourceArray, TargetArray)` like this:

```
char[] input = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char[] inputnew;     

Array.Copy(input, inputNew);    

Array.Reverse(inputnew);
Console.WriteLine(new string(input));
Console.WriteLine(new string(inputnew));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only possible answer — and may be the correct one — is that you're not actually copying the array. When you write

char[] inputnew = input;
you're assigning a reference to the same array into another variable. They're both pointing at the same object, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

in c# arrays are passed by reference. inputnew and input has same indexing when allocation.

if you dont want to pass by reference :

```
char[] inputnew = input.copyTo();
```

will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not assigning a value when you do

```
char[] inputnew = input;
```

What you are doing is pointing **inputnew** to the location of `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };` in the memory.

Therefore, you are getting the same output.

P.s. try to initiate the **inputnew** array first and then assign, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

To make a new array you should use the Array.Copy method,
the way you have it now is that the inputNew is just a reference to input array.

your code should look something like this :

```
        char[] input = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
        char[] inputnew = new char[input.Length];
        Array.Copy(input, inputnew, input.Length);
        Array.Reverse(inputnew);
        Console.WriteLine(new string(input));
        Console.WriteLine(new string(inputnew));
```

Answer (score 0):

you're experiencing this problem because of the behavior of the types on memory. In fact, I suggest you look at the ValueType and reference type topics. Actually **char [] inputnew = input;** at this stage, you look at the input's inputnew (C ++ pointer), so if you want to do a process on the inputnew input process will refer to it as dependent lists. If you don't want to be affected by this process, you should look at the Clone cone.

[look here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)