# Retrieving values from a MultiFloatField in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

*I dug around for similar questions, but none seem to have been asked, so for the sake of potential Google users with the same issue (especially people newer to Unity/Editor scripting/C#), I believe this question ought to exist.*

I was writing a custom property drawer for a class, but for some reason none of the distinct fields were clickable. I was using separate `PropertyField`s for float variables, but decided I'd try and use a [`MultiFloatField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.MultiFloatField.html) to see if it was going to help. Here's what I did:

```
var fwd = property.FindPropertyRelative("Forwards").floatValue;
var bwd = property.FindPropertyRelative("Backwards").floatValue;
var left = property.FindPropertyRelative("StrafeLeft").floatValue;
var right = property.FindPropertyRelative("StrafeRight").floatValue;
EditorGUI.MultiFloatField(position, new [] {"F", "B", "L", "R"}.Select(x => new GUIContent(x)).ToArray(), new [] {fwd, bwd, left, right});
```

Can't live without LINQ. However, when attempting to change the values, they'd immediately reset themselves to whatever their initial value used to be. Given that the `MultiFloatField` method returns nothing, how exactly do you extract the edited values out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is deceptively simple: [Arrays in C# are reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type), which means that editing something in an array preserves the edited value. To illustrate how one would use a MultiFloatField properly, here's an example from [the Unity C# reference](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs#L3616):

```
    // Make an X, Y & Z field for entering a [[Vector3]].
    private static Vector3 Vector3Field(Rect position, Vector3 value)
    {
        s_Vector3Floats[0] = value.x;
        s_Vector3Floats[1] = value.y;
        s_Vector3Floats[2] = value.z;
        position.height = kSingleLineHeight;
        BeginChangeCheck();
        MultiFloatField(position, s_XYZLabels, s_Vector3Floats);
        if (EndChangeCheck())
        {
            value.x = s_Vector3Floats[0];
            value.y = s_Vector3Floats[1];
            value.z = s_Vector3Floats[2];
        }
        return value;
    }
```

As we can see, there's an array (called `s_Vector3Floats`) which is passed into the MultiFloatField; the changed values are read directly from the same array.

Ergo, in the example provided above, the issue lies in the fact that we create a new array every single time. A better (and working!) way to do it would be the following:

```
    var fwd = property.FindPropertyRelative("Forwards");
    var bwd = property.FindPropertyRelative("Backwards");
    var left = property.FindPropertyRelative("StrafeLeft");
    var right = property.FindPropertyRelative("StrafeRight");
    var array = new[] {fwd.floatValue, bwd.floatValue, left.floatValue, right.floatValue};
    EditorGUI.MultiFloatField(position, new [] {"F", "B", "L", "R"}.Select(x => new GUIContent(x)).ToArray(), array);
    fwd.floatValue = array[0];
    bwd.floatValue = array[1];
    left.floatValue = array[2];
    right.floatValue = array[3];
```

And an added bonus: If you're using a [`Foldout`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.Foldout.html) and you can't click on your contents, that's probably because you're giving the Foldout a [Rect that's far too large](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1205700/editorguifoldout-consumes-click-so-guibutton-doesn.html). Be careful with your rects. They, unlike arrays, are value types.