# How to manipulate the faces of a Rubiks Cube represented by a 2D array to perform face rotations

Tags: c#, rubiks-cube

I am creating a project in C# that solves Rubiks Cubes. It will take the current state of the Rubiks Cube in as an input, and output a series of moves to perform to solve the cube using the designated notation.

The Cube is represented by an array of 6 string arrays of length 9:

```
private string[,] CubeState = new string[6,9] {
    { "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE"},
    { "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE"},
    { "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED"},
    { "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN"},
    { "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"},
    { "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW" } };
```

I have created an excel spreadsheet to represent each of the faces[image: representation of cube in 2d]

You can imagine this as a net that folds together to create the cube.

Since I am using a console application and not a windows forms application, I have to represent the cube by writing each face to the console beneath each other. I do this using the following method `PrintCube()`:

```
public void PrintCube()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("--" + CubeState[i,j]);

                if (j % 3 == 2 && j != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\r\n");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        }
    }
```

This makes the standard output of the solved cube this:

[image: Solved Cube Output]

Currently, I am at the stage of coding each different moves that can be performed on the cube, but I have hit a snag.

Here is the code that performs operations:

```
public void PerformOperation(CubeOperations operation)
{
    string[,] newCubeState = CubeState;
    string tempString;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case CubeOperations.F:
            for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
            {
                // Test 1
                tempString = CubeState[4, (3 * (i - 6)) + 2];
                newCubeState[4, (3 * (i - 6)) + 2] = CubeState[3, i - 6];   //258  012
                newCubeState[3, i - 6] = CubeState[2, 3 * (i - 6)];         //012  036
                newCubeState[2, 3 * (i - 6)] = CubeState[1, i];             //036  678
                newCubeState[1, i] = tempString;                            //678  258
                // Test 2
                /*newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[4, i];
                newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[1, i];
                newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[2, i];
                newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[3, i];*/
            }

            RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.WHITE);
        break;

        case CubeOperations.R:
            for (int i = 2; i < 9; i += 3)
            {
                // Test 1
                tempString = CubeState[3, i];
                newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[5, 8 - i];        //258  630
                newCubeState[5, i - 2] = CubeState[1, 10 - i];   //036  852
                newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];            //258  258
                newCubeState[0, i] = tempString;                 //258  258
                // Test 2
                /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[3, i];
                newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];
                newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[1, i - 2];
                newCubeState[3, i - 2] = CubeState[5, i];*/
            }

            RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.RED);
            break;

        case CubeOperations.U:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.L:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.B:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.D:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.FPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.RPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.UPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.LPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.BPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.DPRIME:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.F2:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.R2:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.U2:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.L2:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.B2:
            break;

        case CubeOperations.D2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    CubeState = newCubeState;
}
```

I am coding the operations sequentially and, as such, have only completed the ***F*** operation as of right now, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong on the ***R*** operation.

In Rubik's Cube notation, we see that the operation ***R*** on a solved cube, starting on the white face outwards and a blue face on top, denotes the following movement:

- Hold the cube with the white face out, and the blue face on top.
- Twist the red face 90 degrees clockwise, such that the right-hand side of the white face moves onto the blue face, the green onto the white, the yellow onto the green and the blue onto the yellow.

Doing these two steps results in an ***R*** operation.

To see what we need to do in code for this to happen, let's return to the excel spreadsheet.
[image: representation of cube in 2d]

Starting with the white side, we can see that we must change:

1. indexes *2, 5 and 8* of the **White** face to indexes *2, 5 and 8* on the **Green** face.
2. indexes *2, 5 and 8* of the **Blue** face to indexes*2, 5 and 8* respectively on the **White** Face
3. When we get to the **Yellow** face, however, since the face in the net must "flip" around to connect the orange, blue, green and red faces, we must change indexes *0, 3 and 6*. These each change to indexes *8, 5 and 2* on the **Blue** face respectively. It is easier to think about why this is true if you have a cube in front of you
4. On the **Green** face, we change indexes *2, 5 and 8* to indexes *6, 3 and 0* on the **Yellow** face. Again, this is because of how we interpret the net.

Zooming in on the code for Operation ***R***, we can see how I achieve this:

```
case CubeOperations.R:
    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i += 3)
    {
        //Test 1
        tempString = CubeState[3, i];
        newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[5, 8 - i];       //258  630
        newCubeState[5, i - 2] = CubeState[1, 10 - i];  //036  852
        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];           //258  258
        newCubeState[0, i] = tempString;                //258  258
        // Test 2
        /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[3, i];
        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];
        newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[1, i - 2];
        newCubeState[3, i - 2] = CubeState[5, i];*/
    }
```

I have comments next to each line that states the change taking place, where `//258  630` denotes that the face denoted by `newCubeState` has indexes *2, 5 and 8* changed to what was on the face denoted by `CubeState`'s indexes *6, 3 and 0* respectively.

As seen by the 2d array above, we can see that the first index represents the face becoming **[0] = "WHITE", [1] = "BLUE", [2] = "RED",[3]  = "GREEN", [4] = "ORANGE", [5] = "YELLOW"**

Knowing this, we can interpret my code like this:

- First, the *2nd* index on the **Green** face becomes the *6th* index on the **Yellow** face. **[GREEN -> YELLOW]**
- Second, the *0th* index on the **Yellow** face becomes the *8th* index on the **Blue** Face **[YELLOW -> BLUE]**
- Third, the *2nd* index on the **Blue** face becomes the *2nd* index on the **White** face. **[BLUE -> WHITE]**
- Fourth, the *2nd* index on the **White** face becomes the *2nd* index on the **Green** face. **[WHITE-> GREEN]**

Note that for some strange reason, even though they are completely separate variables, it seems to affect `CubeState[x,y]` when I set `newCubeState[i,j] = CubeState[x, y]`, as such, I need to use an index before it is changed, which leads to needing the temporary variable `tempString`, however, that is not the issue at hand here.

- Fifth, the *5th* index on the **Green** face becomes the *3rd* index on the **Yellow** face. **[GREEN -> YELLOW]**
- Sixth, the *3rd* index on the **Yellow** face becomes the *5th* index on the **Blue** Face **[YELLOW -> BLUE]**
- Seventh, the *5th* index on the **Blue** face becomes the *5th* index on the **White** face. **[BLUE -> WHITE]**
- Eighth, the *5th* index on the **White** face becomes the *5th* index on the **Green** face. **[WHITE-> GREEN]**
- Ninth, the *8th* index on the **Green** face becomes the *0th* index on the **Yellow** face. **[GREEN -> YELLOW]**
- Tenth, the *6th* index on the **Yellow** face becomes the *2nd* index on the **Blue** Face **[YELLOW -> BLUE]**
- Eleventh, the *8th* index on the **Blue** face becomes the *8th* index on the **White** face. **[BLUE -> WHITE]**
- Twelfth, the *8th* index on the **White** face becomes the *8th* index on the **Green** face. **[WHITE-> GREEN]**

This should result in the following output:

---

WHITE - WHITE - GREEN

WHITE - WHITE - GREEN

WHITE - WHITE - GREEN

BLUE - BLUE - WHITE

BLUE - BLUE - WHITE

BLUE - BLUE - WHITE

RED - RED - RED

RED - RED - RED

RED - RED - RED

GREEN - GREEN - YELLOW

GREEN - GREEN - YELLOW

GREEN - GREEN - YELLOW

ORANGE - ORANGE - ORANGE

ORANGE - ORANGE - ORANGE

ORANGE - ORANGE - ORANGE

BLUE - YELLOW - YELLOW

BLUE - YELLOW - YELLOW

BLUE - YELLOW - YELLOW

---

However, we see that this is not the case:

[image: Performing Right Operation]

For some strange reason, we see that the *8th* index on the *3rd* face (**GREEN**) becomes **BLUE** instead of **YELLOW**, as well as the *6th* index on the *5th* face (**YELLOW**), becoming the **WHITE** instead of **BLUE**.

I have no clue why this happens, I would much appreciate help with this.

It shouldn't be causing any problems, but here is my `RotateFaceRight()` method:

```
private void RotateFaceRight(string[,] cube, CubeCenters faceCenterColour)
{
    string[] face = new string[9];
    int faceNumber = (int)faceCenterColour;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        face[i] = cube[(int)faceCenterColour, i];
    }

    /*
     * 012  ->  630
     * 345  ->  741
     * 678  ->  852
     */

    cube[faceNumber, 0] = face[6];
    cube[faceNumber, 1] = face[3];
    cube[faceNumber, 2] = face[0];
    cube[faceNumber, 3] = face[7];
    cube[faceNumber, 4] = face[4];
    cube[faceNumber, 5] = face[1];
    cube[faceNumber, 6] = face[8];
    cube[faceNumber, 7] = face[5];
    cube[faceNumber, 8] = face[2];
}
```

***The rest of my code is here:***

**Cube.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubiks_Cube_Solver
{
    class Cube
    {

        private string[,] CubeState = new string[6, 9] {
            { "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE"},
            { "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE"},
            { "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED"},
            { "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN"},
            { "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"},
            { "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW" } };

        private readonly string[] CubeCenters = new string[] { "WHITE", "BLUE", "RED", "GREEN", "ORANGE", "YELLOW" };
        private readonly string[] CubeSides = new string[] { "FRONT", "TOP", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "LEFT", "BACK" };



        public Cube()
        {

        }


        public void PerformOperation(CubeOperations operation)
        {
            string[,] newCubeState = CubeState;
            string tempString;

            switch (operation)
            {

                //Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}\nOld Face: {2} Old Item: {3}\nNew Face: {4} New Item: {5}\n\n", newCubeState[3, i], CubeState[5, 8 - i], 5, (8 - i), 3, (i));

                case CubeOperations.F:
                    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[4, (3 * (i - 6)) + 2];
                        newCubeState[4, (3 * (i - 6)) + 2] = CubeState[3, i - 6];   //258  012
                        newCubeState[3, i - 6] = CubeState[2, 3 * (i - 6)];         //012  036
                        newCubeState[2, 3 * (i - 6)] = CubeState[1, i];             //036  678
                        newCubeState[1, i] = tempString;                            //678  258
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[4, i];
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[1, i];
                        newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[2, i];
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[3, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.WHITE);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.R:
                    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i += 3)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[3, i];
                        newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[5, 8 - i];       //258  630
                        newCubeState[5, i - 2] = CubeState[1, 10 - i];  //036  852
                        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];           //258  258
                        newCubeState[0, i] = tempString;                //258  258
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[3, i];
                        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[0, i];
                        newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[1, i - 2];
                        newCubeState[3, i - 2] = CubeState[5, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.RED);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.U:
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[4, i];
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[0, i];   //012  012
                        newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[2, i];   //012  012
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[5, i];   //012  012
                        newCubeState[5, i] = tempString;        //012  012
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[2, i];
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[5, i];
                        newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[4, i];
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[0, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.BLUE);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.L:
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i += 3)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[0, i];
                        newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[1, i];       //036  036
                        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[5, i + 2];   //036  258
                        newCubeState[5, i + 2] = CubeState[3, i];   //258  036
                        newCubeState[3, i] = tempString;            //036  036
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[1, i];
                        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[5, i];
                        newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[3, i];
                        newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[0, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.ORANGE);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.B:
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[1, i];
                        newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[2, (i * 3) + 2];     //012  258
                        newCubeState[2, (i * 3) + 2] = CubeState[3, i + 6]; //258  678
                        newCubeState[3, i + 6] = CubeState[4, (i * 3)];     //678  036
                        newCubeState[4, (i * 3)] = tempString;              //036  012
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[1, i] = CubeState[2, i];
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[3, i];
                        newCubeState[3, i] = CubeState[4, i];
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[1, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.YELLOW);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.D:
                    for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
                    {
                        // Test 1
                        tempString = CubeState[2, i];
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[0, i];     //678  678
                        newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[4, i];     //678  678
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[5, i];     //678  678
                        newCubeState[5, i] = tempString;          //678  678
                        // Test 2
                        /*newCubeState[0, i] = CubeState[4, i];
                        newCubeState[2, i] = CubeState[0, i];
                        newCubeState[5, i] = CubeState[2, i];
                        newCubeState[4, i] = CubeState[5, i];*/
                    }

                    RotateFaceRight(newCubeState, Rubiks_Cube_Solver.CubeCenters.GREEN);
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.FPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.RPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.UPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.LPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.BPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.DPRIME:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.F2:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.R2:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.U2:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.L2:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.B2:
                    break;

                case CubeOperations.D2:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            CubeState = newCubeState;
        }


        private void RotateFaceRight(string[,] cube, CubeCenters faceCenterColour)
        {
            string[] face = new string[9];
            int faceNumber = (int)faceCenterColour;

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                face[i] = cube[(int)faceCenterColour, i];
            }

            /*
             * 012  ->  630
             * 345  ->  741
             * 678  ->  852
             */

            cube[faceNumber, 0] = face[6];
            cube[faceNumber, 1] = face[3];
            cube[faceNumber, 2] = face[0];
            cube[faceNumber, 3] = face[7];
            cube[faceNumber, 4] = face[4];
            cube[faceNumber, 5] = face[1];
            cube[faceNumber, 6] = face[8];
            cube[faceNumber, 7] = face[5];
            cube[faceNumber, 8] = face[2];
        }


        public void PrintCube()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("--" + CubeState[i, j]);

                    if (j % 3 == 2 && j != 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\r\n");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**CubeCenters.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubiks_Cube_Solver
{
    enum CubeCenters
    {
        WHITE,
        BLUE,
        RED,
        GREEN,
        ORANGE,
        YELLOW
    }
}
```

**CubeOperations.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubiks_Cube_Solver
{
    enum CubeOperations
    {
        F,
        R,
        U,
        L,
        B,
        D,
        FPRIME,
        RPRIME,
        UPRIME,
        LPRIME,
        BPRIME,
        DPRIME,
        F2,
        R2,
        U2,
        L2,
        B2,
        D2
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rubiks_Cube_Solver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cube cube = new Cube();
            cube.PerformOperation(CubeOperations.R);
            cube.PrintCube();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is int\[\] a reference type or a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type)

Comment: `string[,] newCubeState = CubeState;`, these are references to the same (only) cube state array. So changing it with one variable automatically "updates" the other variable/property.

Comment: You might want to use enums or constants for the sides and blocks of the cube. Expressions like `newCubeState[2, 3 * (i - 6)]` are not very readable and you always have to check what indices correspond to which side/piece.

Comment: @Progman my main issue isn't the referencing of the cube state array, it is that the incorrect result is displayed, but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: In your `CubeOperations.R` part, why do you write `CubeState[5, 8 - i]` and then use different indices `newCubeState[5, i - 2]` in the next line? Shouldn't they be the same similar to all the other cases you have wrote?

Comment: @Progman It is simply a matter of perspective. It's difficult to explain this without a diagram but i'll try. When performing an ***R*** operation, from the green face's perspective, the yellow side is moved up to the 258 positions, lending you to believe that the indexes being used are the yellow's 258, but they are not. If we look from the yellow's perspective, we can see that it is actually the 036 positions that are being moved, because we view the yellow face with blue on the top and green on the bottom, unlike the green face which is white on top and yellow on bottom. [1/2]

Comment: @Progman Furthermore, we see that it isn't a simple 258 -> 036. We see that the top of the yellow face goes to  the bottom of the green face, and vice versa. This means that it is actually 258 -> 630, which the first line expresses.

Next, when we work out what the yellow face becomes, we look from the yellow face’s perspective. This means that we need to figure out what 036 becomes. It becomes apparent when handling a cube that we must use the blue face’s 258 positions. Again, the top of the blue face goes to the bottom of the yellow face, and vice versa meaning we get 036 -> 852 [2/2]

Comment: Keep in mind, `newCubeState` and `CubeState` is the same array. You have not created a new array or copy of the `CubeState` array. In combination with that, when you override the value in `newCubeState[5, i - 2]`, the previous old value gets lost, unless you save it. However, you don't save it. So at that point you are missing information about your cube. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: @Progman I get that, but I don't see any reason to create a temporary value at that position. The way I see it, I use each face twice. When I use that face's value (let's say face1) to change another face's value (let's say face 2) this doesn't change face1's value. The other way is when I use another face (let's say face3) to change face1's value. The changing of the face's value must be done after said face's value is used. This is why I only have one tempString, for the first value that is changed.

Comment: You are doing it right in the case for the **F** operation, but not for the **R** operation. Where do you save or use the value of `newCubeState[5, i - 2]` before you overwrite it? The same question goes for `newCubeState[1, i]`, where do you save or use the value of that cell before overwriting it?

Comment: `newCubeState[5, i - 2]` and `newCubeState[1, i]` do not need saving. The values for the 5 and 1 faces respectively are used before being overwritten. After overwriting these faces, I do not use their values again so I do not need temporary variables to save their values. The only values that are used after they are overwritten are the values for the 3rd face

Comment: @Progman Going through the operation, we see that: First, the 3rd face is stored in a temporary value for use later. Next, the 3rd face is overwritten by the 5th face. Then, after having already been used, the 5th face is overwritten by the 1st face. Then, the 1st face is overwritten by the 0th face. Finally, the 0th face is overwritten by what should be the 3rd face, but that has been overwritten already so we instead use the temporary value we saved for it earlier. At no point in the operation is a face’s value being overwritten before it is used to change another value.

Comment: You are reading from `CubeState[5, 8 - i]` (in the line before), but writing in `newCubeState[5, i - 2]`. These are different indices, so the previous value of `newCubeState[5, i - 2]` get lost. Same for `CubeState[1, 10 - i]` (in the line before) and `newCubeState[1, i]`, different indices again.

Comment: @Progman I see now. Whilst I am changing the face's in the correct order, the indices are still getting overwritten because they are different. i.e. face 5 index 6 is being used, but then face 5 index 0 is changed, not index 6? I will implement this change now and check to see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Progman This seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure how I missed that when I went through my program the first time. Thanks.