# Passing a stack variable as an event argument

Tags: c#

I have an event broker that exposes an `EventHandler<T>` that allows observers to inspect the event argument and, if needed, modify it. While this works okay, I would ideally like to ensure that `T` only lives on the stack and, furthermore, that no component is able to take a reference to T, thereby extending its lifetime.

```
public class Game // mediator pattern
{
  public event EventHandler<Query> Queries; // effectively a chain

  public void PerformQuery(object sender, Query q)
  {
    Queries?.Invoke(sender, q);
  }
}
```

Sadly, a `ref struct` cannot be used as a generic argument:

```
ref struct Query {} // EventHandler<Query> not allowed
```

And similarly I cannot imbue `EventHandler`'s `TEventArgs` with any sort of 'use structs, pass by reference' mechanics.

Now, in C#, we *can* decide whether variables live on the stack on the heap, e.g. with `stackalloc` and such, so what I'm after, I guess, is just a way of getting something equivalent to a `ref struct` inside an event.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get to decide this.  Where variables live is an implementation detail in c#.

Comment: Ok, if you really want to extend lifetime, consider a mechanism like an object pool or an ioc container that has lifetime management features.

Comment: Also, this might work out better if you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Clarification added.

Comment: The stackalloc you refer to is intended for temporary allocations inside methods, not persistent state storage.

Comment: I *don't* want persistent state storage. That's the whole point. A query gets thrown around the app, then it gets destroyed. I want exactly that.

Comment: And an ordinary object won't suffice for that?  Why would something like that need to be stored on the stack?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Comment: See also [Why ref structs cannot be used as type arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50871135)

Answer (score 2):

While [`stackalloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) applied/wrapped in a very convoluted way may (probably) give you some semblance of `variables live on the stack on the heap`, it will not be what `stackalloc` is [intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721277/when-would-i-need-to-use-the-stackalloc-keyword-in-c) for.

So I'd rather propose to concentrate on the `no component is able to take a reference to T, thereby extending its lifetime` part.

To get it we need

1. Wrapper class (probably, but not necessary with corresponding interface)
2. Implementing [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)
3. And storing the actual `T` as [WeakReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?view=netframework-4.8)

It will be something like

```
public interface ITakeNoRefClass
{
    void Change(string value);
}

public class TakeNoRefClass : ITakeNoRefClass
{
    ...
}

public class TakeNoRefClassWrapper : ITakeNoRefClass, IDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private readonly WeakReference<TakeNoRefClass> _takeNoRefWeakRef;

    public TakeNoRefClassWrapper(WeakReference<TakeNoRefClass> takeNoRefWeakRef)
    {
        _takeNoRefWeakRef = takeNoRefWeakRef;
    }

    public void Change(string value)
    {
        Execute(o => o.Change(value));
    }

    private void Execute(Action<ITakeNoRefClass> action)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("You should not have taken this ref");
        }
        var target = _takeNoRefWeakRef.Target;
        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("You should not have taken this ref");
        }
        action(target);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

And it should be used like

```
public void CreateObjectAndRaiseEvents()
{
    var target = new TakeNoRefClass();
    // Passing it into a separate method to ensure that it won't be GC'ed before executing all event handlers.
    RaiseEvents(target);
}

private void RaiseEvent(TakeNoRefClass target)
{
    using (var wrapper = new TakeNoRefClassWrapper(new WeakReference<TakeNoRefClass>(target))
    {
        _event?.Invoke(wrapper);
    }
}
```